# How to tell if SQL Server user can view every table in database

Tags: sql-server

I have an application that lets users browse data in a SQL database, and I'd like to warn the user if they don't have rights to see every table. I'm getting a list of tables by doing a SELECT on sys.objects, but if the user doesn't have SELECT rights on a table, it doesn't show up in that query, so there's no way I can see to know what I don't know.

I don't even need to know what in particular I'm missing, just if there's **anything** the user can't view. Anybody know how to accomplish this?

**CLARIFICATION:**

I'm creating a tool that can be run against any SQL Server, so I'm not looking to set up permissions to see every object - I just want to know if the current user can. If they don't have rights, that's fine - I just want to make sure they know that, since the results they get won't reflect the entire database.

Comment: If you want a user to know what they can't see, they need different credentials somehow that can see other objects. They will *never* see otherwise: which makes your "clarification" look confusing...

Comment: @gbn: I was hoping for something like a query that says "this database has 100 tables in it" when selecting a list of tables only shows 30, meaning I can't see everything. Maybe it's just wishful thinking, but I just wanted a "yes, this is everything" or "no, this isn't everything", but it's sounding like that's not possible. For now, I'll just check if they're a member of any database roles that can see everything and call that good enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure if this is in line with any security concerns of yours, but my idea would be to create a user called SELECT_ALL that has select rights to all tables, create a connection with SELECT_ALL and query the sys.objects table, pass the list of tables (or just a count(*) if you want to simply know if the user has complete access or anything less than complete), close the connection, then repeat with the user's credentials and compare.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mask the sys.objects query with a user with different permissions that *can* see the lot. The best way is `EXECUTE AS OWNER` in a view or udf. This enumerates all objects (if dbo owns everything) thus allowing you to find out what is missing (which is masked by [metadata visibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187113%28SQL.90%29.aspx))

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.mymask
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER --the magic
AS
SELECT * FROM sys.objects
GO

SELECT 
   *
FROM
   dbo.mymask v
   LEFT JOIN
   sys.objects o2 ON v.object_id = o.object_id
```

If you use roles, or want to do it in one then something like

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.mymask
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER --the magic
AS
SELECT ...
FROM
   sys.objects O
   JOIN
   sys.database_permissions DP ON ...     --premissions
   JOIN
   sys.database_principals R ON DP. = R  --role
   etc to role members etc
WHERE
   xxx.name = ORIGINAL_LOGIN()
GO
```